# How to get data from flask database using javascript?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to display users in select box from flask database but the select is handled by javascript. How do I pass information to javascript?

Comment: flask is not a database. Please post your code and a more specific description of your issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Jinja. The list of users from the database can be passed by rendering the template as follows. In the given example, I passed a list of keys that is obtained from a separate function. It was iterated over in index.html with the option tag using the Jinja syntax.

**App.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', keyset = keys)
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
{% block body %}
                <select name="example" id="names">
                    {% for key in keyset %}
                    <option value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for posting such a detailed answer. Note that this will render on server side rather than using javascript.